# The uniqueness and existence of optimal solution

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**My question:** For $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, consider the function: $J: \mathbb{R}^{n+2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
J\left(v:=\left(v_0, \ldots, v_{n+1}\right)\right)=h \sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{v_{i+1}-v_i}{h}\right)^2},
$$
where $h=\frac{1}{n+1}$
We consider the problem of minimizing $J$ on the set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ defined by:
$$
K:=\left\{v=\left(v_0, \ldots, v_{n+1}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+2}, v_0=0, v_{n+1}=1\right\}
$$
Discuss the existence, the uniqueness, and characterize the (or) possible solution (s).
**My attempt**: I can prove that J is a strictly convex function on $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ and $K$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$. That means if there exists a solution for the problem, it will be unique. But i don't know how to show the existence of solution. I used to think about the compactness but $K$ is only closed.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $v_{i-1}$ and $v_{i+1},$ you can prove much more elementarily that $f(x):=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{v_{i+1}-x}h\right)^2}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x-v_{i-1}}h\right)^2}$ is minimal iff $v_{i+1}-x=x-v_{i-1}:$ juste notice that
$f'(x)=\frac a{\sqrt{1+a^2}}-\frac b{\sqrt{1+b^2}}$ with $a=\frac{x-v_i}h$ and $b=\frac{v_{i+1}-x}h,$ and that $t\mapsto\frac t{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ is increasing.

Hence $J(v)$ is minimal iff $\forall i\quad v_i=ih,$ and its minimal value is $\sqrt2.$

Comment: Can you prove it more detail? I intend to apply Minkowski inequality to prove that minimal value of J is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I added some details. Is it sufficient for you now?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Anne

Comment: [Welcome](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer @Pipnap